# Intercepting function calls to other files/applications on Windows?

Tags: iis

Take w3wp.exe for example. Which Windows API or Windows COM function call is used to communicate between  between svchost.exe and w3wp.exe? How about the function call that is used to communicate between HTTP.sys and w3wp.exe?
See diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyN2W.png

Comment: What's your purpose of learning that? IIS has provided you API to extend its functionality, but I do not see a need to inject into the fields you mentioned.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its intention is questionable.

Comment: Do you need one time information for debugging purposes, or a way to do this via your own program that monitors everything. The approach is different depending on which you want. Your question really sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain why you want to intercept the call, there may be a better way to reach your real goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to ***see*** the function calls and get the data that was passed in as arguments, I highly recommend [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor). It lets you hook in to most DLL's built in to windows out of the box and lets you monitor passed arguments to functions and the functions return values.

[image]

If you are wanting to watch a dll that is the program does not already know about you can add it to the program. However, to add it to the program you will need to write a XML descriptor file for the dll describing the data-types and arguments for the functions the dll contains. The descriptor files fairly simple, it is basically just translating the dll's `.h` you would have already for it in to a XML format (if you don't have a header file it will be a lot harder though). For example here is what the descriptor for `Loadperf.dll` is

```xml
<!--
    API Monitor Definitions
    (c) 2010-2012, Rohitab Batra <rohitab@rohitab.com>
    http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor/
-->
<ApiMonitor>
    <Include Filename="Headers\windows.h.xml" />
    <Module Name="Loadperf.dll" CallingConvention="STDCALL" ErrorFunc="GetLastError" OnlineHelp="MSDN">
        <!-- Performance Counters -->
        <Category Name="Diagnostics/Performance Counters" />
        <Api Name="LoadPerfCounterTextStrings" BothCharset="True">
            <Param Type="LPCTSTR" Name="commandLine" />
            <Param Type="BOOL" Name="bQuietModeArg" />
            <Return Type="[ERROR_CODE]" />
        </Api>
        <Api Name="UnloadPerfCounterTextStrings" BothCharset="True">
            <Param Type="LPCTSTR" Name="commandLine" />
            <Param Type="BOOL" Name="bQuietModeArg" />
            <Return Type="[ERROR_CODE]" />
        </Api>
    </Module>
</ApiMonitor>
```

---

If you are wanting to write code and have it ***intercept*** the calls and modify the arguments passed or the result returned, I recommend [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/). It is not difficult at all to do. [Here is a good description](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking) of it and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[DeviceIOControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) perhaps, between w3wp.exe and http.sys?  I don't have the source code to these modules.  You can however get the debug symbols for various Windows components, and get skilled in debugging, and use other debuggers/utils such as [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).  It's a good learning exercise if that's your ultimate goal.

Your question is a bit vague, not sure what you're trying to achieve.